# Grunt concat from index like Brocoli

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to have something likes this:

```
 app.import('path/to/file.js');
 app.import('path/to/file.css');
```

And it would concate everything. Is there a way using Grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the sample gruntfile on the Grunt site.

http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

Use the standard grunt file specifications. How to specify files is here:

http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files

Note that you do not have to add files one at a time. That's why they allow wild cards. You specify entire directory trees if you want. And mostly this is what you want. Study the file glob patterns on the grunt site. There are lots of examples too.

Comment: Thank you but I'd need to modify the Gruntfile each time I add a lib :/

Comment: And what about bower?

Comment: Sounds like a new question. :)